# Ruby Enterprise Edition crashes in gc_sweep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My Rails application crashes **intermittently** with the following message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/multibyte/utils.rb:52: [BUG] gc_sweep(): unknown data type 0x0(0xbdc2ca0)
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01
```

I am running the app on Nginx / Passenger.

Ruby 1.8.7 Enterprise Edition 2010.10, Rails 2.3.5, Ubuntu 9.10 32bit.

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: I presume you mean Ruby Enterprise Edition, rather than Rails Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I modified my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch back to Ruby MRI. It is a temporary solution though. Hopefully, this problem will be fixed in the next release of REE.

Answer (score 0):

try opening an issue at:
http://github.com/FooBarWidget/rubyenterpriseedition187-248/issues